# Inequality of products

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have to show the following result:

Let $t_i$, $u_i \in [0,1]$ for $1≤i≤s$ and let $v \in [0,1]$ be such that $|t_i-u_i| ≤ v$ for  $1≤i≤s$. Then $$\left| \prod_{i=1}^{s}t_i - \prod_{i=1}^{s}u_i \right|≤s\cdot v$$ and $$\left| \prod_{i=1}^{s}t_i - \prod_{i=1}^{s}u_i \right|≤1-(1-v)^s$$
I also found the question in this forum but nobody answered it. Can someone help me please to show the inequalities and answer which estimation is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can youse induction for both inequalities and also to check witch estimation is better.

For the estimation you get then with $s=1$

$$1-(1-v) ≤ sv \Longrightarrow v ≤ vs \Longrightarrow0≤s$$

The next step is $ s \mapsto s+1 $ then you geht

$$ 1-(1-v)^{s+1} =1-(1-v)^s(1-v) = sv + (1-v)^sv = v(s+1)$$

so it follows that $1-(1-v)^s ≤ sv \;\forall s \in \mathbb{N}$